# From original dataset, find the probability of each element in each row having the maximum value in its row

Tags: list-manipulation, maximum

Suppose I have this dataset

```
{{1, 3, 5}, {4, 4, 2}, {5, 3, 5}, {10, 4, 10}} // MatrixForm
```

How do I find the probability that each cell is the maximum in its row.

So for example in the first row,

```
{1, 3, 5}
```

The probability of the first element being max is 0 (since its value is 1 while the third element has value 5). The probability of the second element being max is 0 (since its value is 3 while the third element has value 5). The probability of the third element being max is 1 (since its value is 5).

For the second row:

```
{4,4,2}
```

The probability of the first element being max is 1/2 (since its value is 4 equal to the second element). The probability of the second element being max is 1/2 (since its value is 4 equal to the first element). The probability of the third element being max is 0 (since its value is 2 while the first and the second elements have value 4).

Thanks all!

Comment: As @JimB has nicely explained [below](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/272017/764) you are using the term _probability_, but what are are really talking about is _relevance_ or _degree of truthfullness_ (e.g., as in a fuzzy membership function indicating the degree of belonging to the set of unique row maxima). That is not the same and it would be better to not talk about probability here.

Answer (score 5):

I am sure there are lots of ways to do this. One could be a direct approach. Find the max of each row. Then iterate over each row. if element is not max, give zero, else 1 divided by number of maximum elements in that row.

Using `MapIndex` to match the max of each row with the current row being iterated over.

```
mat = {{1, 3, 5}, {4, 4, 2}, {5, 3, 5}, {10, 4, 10}};
max = Map[Max[#] &, mat];
f[row_List, max_?NumericQ]:= With[{z = Count[row, max]}, If[# != max, 0, 1/z] & /@ row];
MapIndexed[f[#, max[[First[#2]]]] &, mat]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Thanks, very helpful. I know it is not that difficult, but I just didn't know which library to look up. I will check MaxIndexed now.

Answer (score 4):

We first solve the problem for a single list (a vector). It is then easy to apply it to a list of lists (a matrix).

**A single list.** One can use

```
f[a_List] := Thread[a==Max[a]] /. {True->1,False->0} // #/Total[#]&
```

For example

```
f[{4,4,2}]
(* {1/2,1/2,0} *)
```

**A list of lists.** To apply `f` to each row, use `Map[f,...]` as in

```
Map[f,{{1,3,5},{4,4,2},{5,3,5},{10,4,10}}]
(* {{0,0,1},{1/2,1/2,0},{1/2,0,1/2},{1/2,0,1/2}} *)
```

Answer (score 4):

You could write

```
f = #/Total[#, {2}] &[UnitStep[# - Max /@ #]] &;
f[list]
(* {{0, 0, 1}, {1/2, 1/2, 0}, {1/2, 0, 1/2}, {1/2, 0, 1/2}} *)
```

Answer (score 2):

This is an extended comment to challenge you and the other folks giving answers so far.

I’m going to attempt to argue that your question either makes no sense or at least is incomplete for two reasons.

1. You have not stated anything about the probabilistic
   process of arranging items in a row or if the probabilistic process
   is about how a cell in a row is selected.  Therefore, given a
   dataset, the probabilities will be either 0 or 1.
2. The assignment of a probability of 1/2 makes no sense unless
   you add in a more specific definition of your objective and a
   description of the probabilistic process.  For example, that might
   be “the probability that each cell is the *only* cell equal to the
   maximum in its row” (which still only allows probabilities of zero or
   one) or “the probability that a randomly selected cell equals the
   maximum in its row”.  If the number of items in a row is $n$ and the
   number of cells with the same value of the maximum is $n_{\text{max}}$, then
   with the latter definition the probability of a randomly selected
   cell having the maximum value is $n_{\text{max}}/n$.  For rows with 3 cells (as
   in your example, that probability can only be 1/3, 2/3, or 1 and not 1/2.

In short you've described no probabilistic process and that is essential.

Answer (score 2):

```
la = {{1, 3, 5}, {4, 4, 2}, {5, 3, 5}, {10, 4, 10}};
```

Using `Rescale` and `Boole`

```
Rescale[#, {0, Count[#, 1]}] &[Boole @ Thread[# == Max[#]]] & /@ la
```

[image]

Another test

```
lb = {{2, 2, 2, 2}, {2, 2, 2, 1}, {2, 2, 1, 1}, {2, 1, 1, 1}};
```

```
 Rescale[#, {0, Count[#, 1]}] &[Boole @ Thread[# == Max[#]]] & /@ lb
```

[image]